# Execute multiple lines in orElseThrow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, stream

I have the following code block that throws exception if the user is not found. On the other hand, in addition to throwing exception, I also want to call a method when user is not found. So, can I call it by adding another `.orElseThrow` etc. or shall I convert this block in a standard if condition?

```
final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getUsername())
                .orElseThrow(InvalidCredentialsException::new);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do like it:

```
final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getUsername())
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                                System.out.println("multiple lines");
                                return new InvalidCredentialsException();
                                });
```